# Поиск данных из бд с помощью формы YII2?

Tags: yii2, checkbox

Здравствуйте, у меня есть своя форма с чекбоксами и инпутами. Я хочу чтобы после выбора нужных параметров при нажатии кнопки "Показать" у меня выводились нужные записи из БД.

```
<fieldset class="search-column">
    <legend>Тип жилья:</legend>
    <ul class="type-checkbox">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" id="hotel-field" checked>
        <label for="hotel-field">Гостиница</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="motel" id="motel-field" checked>
        <label for="motel-field">Мотель</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apart" id="apart-field" checked>
        <label for="apart-field">Аппартаменты</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="search-column-range">
    <div class="range-title">Стоимость в сутки(Р):</div>
    <div class="price-filter">
      <div class="min-price">
        <input type="text" name="start-price" id="start-price-field">
        <label for="start-price-field">от 0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="max-price">
        <input type="text" name="final-price" id="final-price-field">
        <label for="final-price-field">до 3000</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="show-hotels" type="submit">Показать</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

У меня пока что сделан обычный вывод всех данных из нужной таблицы бд с пагинацией.

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article):?>


      <img src="" alt="">

      <a href="#"><?= $article->hotelname?></a>
      <?= $article->type?>
      От <?= $article->min_price?> Р.
      <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
      <a href="#">Забронировать</a>


  <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php
      echo LinkPager::widget([
          'pagination' => $pagination,
      ]);
    ?>
```

Я не очень понимаю как при помощи Yii2 можно связать чекбоксы и инпуты с бд и выводить данные когда нужно.
Помогите пожалуйста.
Хожу вокруг да около GridView вроде через это можно вывести, но до меня совсем не доходит как.

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет виджет GridView
Он принимает параметром $dataProvider -  это класс, который реализует yii\data\DataProviderInterface.

Так как провайдеров несколько то оставлю ссылку на документацию. https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/output-data-providers/

Вот пример вывода данного виджета

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'parent_id',
        'name:ntext',
        'url:ntext',
        'category_image:ntext',
        // 'created_at',
        // 'updated_at',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: А в самих чекбоксах нужно какой-то php код прописывать? Чтобы значения получать от них? И для GridView нужно писать что-то в контроллере или в моделе? или сразу можно выводить на страницу?

Comment: Собственно на основании данных вашей формы будет строится запрос в базу($query) а на основании query собираться $dataProvider.
А уже из данных $dataProvider строится GridView

Comment: А при выводе gridView он будет использовать свои стили? или можно как-то сделать, чтобы визуально все осталось как у меня?)

Comment: Конечно вы можете кастомизировать таблицу  с помощью css .

Comment: Вывел данные на страницу с помощью GridView, подскажите пожалуйста, как теперь связать вывод с чекбоксами и инпутом?, чтобы запрос автоматически создавался в зависимости от активных чекбоксов

$query = Article::find()->where(['swimmingpool' => 1]);

Сейчас запрос такой, то есть выдергивает записи напрямую из бд

Comment: Для этого ловите POST который отправляется формой и на основании этого стройте выборку из базы